# Design stack with push/pop/midPop in O(1) and getMin in less than O(N). Space not constraint

Tags: data-structures, stack

Problem statement -

Design a stack which has push, pop, pop middle element in O(1) time complexity and getMin() should have time complexity < O(N). Space complexity no constraint.

Question is - how to achieve getMin() in time complexity less than O(N) considering we have to support all other 3 operation (push/pop/midPop) in O(1) time complexity.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is question clear now?

Comment: Needs more details. Right now, it's just an open question without motivation or attempt at solution. Is amortized cost acceptable? Perhaps you can redesign your algorithm so it doesn't need these exact requirements, or you can impose a constraint on your data set (e.g., no more than 65000 items). A concrete scenario would help people find solutions which would be practical for your real-world problem space.